# How to speed up Mail() PHP code

Tags: php, performance, email

My code works, but when customers add two or more pictures in the web form and press send, my website loads really slow. It takes about 1 minute to load and 1-3 minutes to actually send.

How can I speed up this process?

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['namecontact']) && !empty($_POST['namecarinfo'])) {

    $contacts = array(
        //"autoperka.info@gmail.com",
        //"automobiliukas24@gmail.com",
        //  "ruslanneviadomskij@gmail.com",
        "gabriele.giniot@gmail.com"
    );

    foreach($contacts as $contact) {


        $recipient_email = $contact; //recepient
        $from_email = $_POST['namecontact']; //from email using site domain.
        $subject = $from_email . " SupirkimasPlius.lt"; //email subject line

        $sender_name = $_POST["namecontact"];
        $sender_car = $_POST["namecarinfo"];
        $sender_message = 'Automobilio pasiūlymas:
          Marke/modelis:' . $_POST["namecarinfo"] . 'Kontaktai/miestas:' . $_POST["namecontact"] . 'Komentaras:' . $_POST["namecoment"];

        $attachments = $_FILES['namephoto'];

        $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
        $boundary = md5(time());






        if($file_count > 0) { //if attachment exists
            //header
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "From:" . $from_email . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $sender_car . "" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

            //message text
            $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
            $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
            $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($sender_message));

            //attachments
            for($x = 0; $x < $file_count; $x++) {
                if(!empty($attachments['name'][$x])) {

                    /*if($attachments['error'][$x]>0) //exit script and output error if we encounter any
                    {
                    $mymsg = array(
                    1=>"Įkeltos nuotraukos/ų dydis per didelis",
                    2=>"Įkeltos nuotraukos/ų dydis per didelis",
                    3=>"Įkėlimo klaida, pabandykite dar kartą",
                    4=>"Nėra įkeltų nuotraukų",
                    6=>"Įkėlimo klaida" );
                    die($mymsg[$attachments['error'][$x]]);
                    }*/

                    //get file info
                    $file_name = $attachments['name'][$x];
                    $file_tmp_name = $attachments['tmp_name'][$x];
                    $file_size = $attachments['size'][$x];
                    $file_type = $attachments['type'][$x];


                    //read file
                    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
                    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                    fclose($handle);
                    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

                    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";

                    $body .= "Content-Type: $file_type; name=\"$file_tmp_name\"\r\n";
                    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_tmp_name\"\r\n";
                    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                    $body .= "X-Attachment-Id: " . rand(1000, 99999) . "\r\n\r\n";
                    $body .= $encoded_content;
                }
            }

        } else { //send plain email otherwise
            $headers = "From:" . $from;
            $body = $sender_message;
        }




        $sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    } //foreach uzdaro


}


if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {
    $myfile = fopen("success.php", "r") or die(fopen("index.php", "r"));
    echo fread($myfile, filesize("success.php"));
    fclose($myfile);
    //mail('gabriele.giniot@gmail.com',$subject,$message,$headers);
    //mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2); // sends a copy of the message to the sender


} else {
    $myfile = fopen("failed.php", "r") or die(fopen("index.php", "r"));
    echo fread($myfile, filesize("failed.php"));
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: where is the mail server, how big are the pictures, how fast is the system?

Comment: Do not use mail - use phpmailer, or swiftmail or another one of the exceptional libraries that exist out there.

Comment: There are lots of factors. Your client's upload speed, your server's download speed. And then your upload speed to your smtp server if you are not using your smtp server. And not to mention your system speed for handling the attachment. What I would suggest you to do is validate the image sizes and probably reduce the sizes of image using javascript before uploading to your server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your images are to big and your upload-rate to small or your system/mail-server is to slow. But you could try [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). this would reduce your codes complexity and maybe also improve performance. Also have a look at [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.move-uploaded-file.php). Your code would then look something like this

```
//first upload your attachments to a temp-directory (tmp/)
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_FILES['namephoto']['tmp_name']); $i++)
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['namephoto']['tmp_name'][$i], 'tmp/'.$_FILES['namephoto']['name'][$i]);

//initialize phpmailer
$mail = new PHPMailer ();

//set smtp credentials
$mail->Host       = 'smtp1.example.com';     // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                    // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';      // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'secret';                // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                   // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587;

//set from-address
$mail->setFrom ($_POST['namecontact']);

//add recipients
foreach ($contacts as $contact)
    $mail->addAddress ($contact);

//add attachments
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($_FILES['namephoto']['name']); $i++)
    $mail->addAttachment ('tmp/'.$_FILES['namephoto']['name'][$i]);

//set subject and body
$mail->Subject = $from_email.' SupirkimasPlius.lt';
$mail->Body    = 'Automobilio pasiūlymas: Marke/modelis: '.$_POST["namecarinfo"].' Kontaktai/miestas: '.$_POST["namecontact"].'Komentaras:'.$_POST["namecoment"];

//send your mail
$sentMail = $mail->send ();

//check if successfully sent
if ($sentMail) {...} else {...}
```